# Installing GHC on WSL

Tags: haskell, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu on WSL for Windows 10 in order to get ready for the Marlowe Pioneers Program. I figure I will need to install GHC and Cabal next in order to install the Cardano-CLI and Marlowe-CLI.

Can someone please tell me the best way to install GHC and Cabal on WSL/Ubuntu?
Much Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to install Haskell on Linux is by using GHCUP. Using `apt` may install an old version of GHC.

Simply enter the following command on your WSL terminal:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
```

It depends on your use case. If you would like to develop using Haskell, I would recommend installing Stack too. Note that you should not install the Haskell Language Server if you plan on using VS Code. VS Code will download it for you, depending on your GHC version.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to use wsl2 on windows, if you aren't already, as you will have build issues.

https://winaero.com/set-linux-distro-version-to-wsl-1-or-wsl-2-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Found two great resources from the Plutus Pioneers Program
youtu.be/mnfItts6VbU and
youtu.be/g2F9raiGp_s

I had to jump around a bit because these videos are for Plutus not Marlowe but there was good information on installing WSL-Ubuntu, Cabal, Nix, and VSCode

Haskell was installed at the linux terminal window with the following command

```
sudo apt install ghc
```